# Compute sequence of summed fractions in R

Tags: r, sum, logic, sequence, fractions

I want to compute the following sequence using R, without loops, i.e. for cycles.

```
1 + (2/3) + ((2/3)*(4/5)) + ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7)) + ... + ((2/3)*(4/5)*...(20/21))
```

So far, I tried different approaches with a sequence as well as a while function, but could not came up with a suitable solution. Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `cumprod`

```
v1 <- seq(2, 20, by = 2)
v2 <- seq(3, 21, by = 2)
1 + sum(cumprod(v1/v2))
[1] 4.945724
```

-manual calculation

```
1 + (2/3) + ((2/3)*(4/5)) + ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7)) + ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7) * (8/9)) + ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7) * (8/9) * (10/11)) +  ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7) * (8/9) * (10/11) * (12/13)) + ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7) * (8/9) * (10/11) * (12/13) * (14/15)) + ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7) * (8/9) * (10/11) * (12/13) * (14/15) * (16/17)) +  ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7) * (8/9) * (10/11) * (12/13) * (14/15) * (16/17) * (18/19)) + ((2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7) * (8/9) * (10/11) * (12/13) * (14/15) * (16/17) * (18/19) * (20/21))
[1] 4.945724
```

Comment: This solution is very accurate and is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much for the quick help.